# Clients getting random ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED error when connecting to Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Our app is running on Google App Engine python2.7 standard environment. Since 8 March 2021, there have been hundreds of user reports of getting ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED when firing API requests to the app from browsers.

Affected browsers include latest versions of Chrome, Safari, Firefox and Edge, so it is unlikely to be a problem of specific browsers/extensions. Also, similar problems are occurring in our native Android/iOS apps connecting to the same APIs on app engine.

When we check the log viewer on Google Cloud console, we can see that although the browser is reporting ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED, the request has actually been passed to an instance and a 200 OK response has been produced successfully without errors. This shows that the particular client is able to connect to the server and send the request every time this issue occurs, but it cannot receive any response.

Furthermore, from the application logs, we can see that sometimes a request is sent twice within 2-4 seconds. Since our client application itself doesn't send 2 same requests, this is likely due to client retrying after connection is closed. Our API handlers are less optimized and can take up to 10 seconds to produce a response, but this is well within the 60s limit on app engine. Our API handlers also do not write partial response. The response is written after all processing is done.

Seemingly, the issue only affects a small proportion of our users, and it doesn't affect all of their requests to the same service. When a user is affected, changing browsers or even devices won't help. When a user like myself is not affected, I can keep refreshing for days and there will be no issues. I have tried logging into an affected user's account but the issue doesn't occur on my end, so it is less likely to be account specific issue in the application level (The application log also confirms this).

relevant parts of `app.yaml` :

```
runtime: python27
service: apis2
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
instance_class: F2

inbound_services:
- warmup

builtins:
- appstats: on
- remote_api: on
- deferred: on

automatic_scaling:
    min_instances: 0
    min_idle_instances: 0
    max_instances: 600
```

Comment: This is a tough one since you are not able to reproduce, I would tend to say that there is something wrong in the API itself, do you get any relevant logs from the API side when the issue occurs?

Comment: Your comment `When a user is affected, changing browsers or even devices won't help` might point to location-based issues. Is there something common to users that are affected? What type of requests are failing and can they be automated to catch the problem?

Comment: @RafaelLemos We can see all the logs from the API side when the issue occurs. They look exactly the same as those for normal API requests that do not result in errors.

Comment: @JohnHanley Location-based issues can be a possibility. Our users are mostly based in Hong Kong and the app engine app is in us-central. We tried asking for ISP information and VPN settings from affected users but we haven't found any patterns yet. Users are also saying that other websites are working fine. The requests are mostly for a CMS system where users log into their own accounts and manage their data. Apparently the requests that fail are the REST api calls made with ajax but occasionally the page request (which is dynamic) is also failing

Comment: One thing to add is that failure doesn't seem to be permanent. But it can be very long lasting for some users. For a few others, the errors may go away after a few refreshes.

Comment: A few months ago a similar problem was reported. The issue turned out to be an ISP issue. I know the problem was resolved. I think it was Hong Kong also. IIRC it was a BGP routing misconfiguration by the ISP in Hong Kong.

Comment: We're seeing similar behavior now the past few weeks. Seemingly random API requests failing due to ConnectionClosedError messages. Did you ever resolve this?